# Does Depth-First-Search admit a quasilinear time algorithm in mutitape Turing Machine model?

Tags: graph-algorithms, circuit-complexity, time-complexity, turing-machines

Depth-First-Search (DFS) has a quasilinear (i.e.,$\widetilde{O}(m+n)$) time algorithm in random access model (RAM). I am curious about whether DFS still admits a $\widetilde{O}(m+n)$ time algorithm in multitape Turing machine model.

Comment: For the "linear" part, I guess no, since you need an extra-factor $O(\log n)$ to read the node IDs.

Comment: I don't care about the log factor. Quasilinear (i.e., $\widetilde{O}(m+n)$) time algorithm will be OK.

Comment: You don't care about in your new edited question. The previous one,  which I commented, asked for "a linear or quasilinear" algorithm.